# Swift BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits Equivalent

Tags: swift, bit, data-conversion

I need Swift implementation of C# BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(doubleValue).
I find C# implementantion on site is only

> https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs

```
 [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static unsafe long DoubleToInt64Bits(double value) {
        /// some comments ....
        Contract.Assert(IsLittleEndian, "This method is implemented assuming little endian with an ambiguous spec.");
        return *((long *)&value);
    }
```

in c# i have method:

```
public long EncodeValue(double doubleValue)
{
    return BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(doubleValue);
}
```

but I need the same functionality in Swift for ios. 
Something like this:

```
func EncodeValue(doubleValue: Double)
{
    return SwiftDoubleToInt64Bits(doubleValue)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`bitPattern`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1849211-bitpattern) property of `Double` returns an (unsigned) 64-bit integer with the same memory representation:

```
let doubleValue = 12.34
let encoded = doubleValue.bitPattern // UInt64
```

The reverse conversion is done with

```
let decoded = Double(bitPattern: encoded)
print(decoded) // 12.34
```

In the same way you can convert between `Float` and `UInt32`.

For a platform independent memory representation (e.g. “big endian”) use

```
let encodedBE = doubleValue.bitPattern.bigEndian
let decoded = Double(bitPattern: UInt64(bigEndian: encodedBE))
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to swap little and big-endian?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Yes!